# Create SVG components with scoped CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am creating React components that will render out various SVGs:

```
const Close = ({
  fill, width, height, float,
}) => (
  <svg width={ `${width}px` } height={ `${height}px` } viewBox="0 0 14.48 14.48" style={ { float: `${float}`, cursor: 'pointer' } }>
    <title>x</title>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
      <g id="Background">
        <line style={ { fill: 'none', stroke: `${fill}`, strokeMiterlimit: 10 } } x1="14.13" y1="0.35" x2="0.35" y2="14.13" />
        <line style={ { fill: 'none', stroke: `${fill}`, strokeMiterlimit: 10 } } x1="14.13" y1="14.13" x2="0.35" y2="0.35" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
);
```

It's very convenient to be able to supply various attributed to this component to control dimensions, colour, etc...

What I don't have a good solution for, however, is handling the styles in a DRY manner. Note the `line` elements have the same value for `style`. I presently have them written inline because if I added an embedded stylesheet, then I would get class name collisions with other SVGs I render elsewhere on the page (our SVG software uses the same classes over and over).

`<style scoped>` has been removed from the spec: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/552

Shadow DOM is not yet supported by Edge: https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1

Is there any other alternative for scoping styles?

Comment: hi @Mister. why don't you go for css-in-js. ?

Comment: @MisterEpic I'm a bit confused as to what you are looking for. Every SVG is pretty much unique right so why would you want to share styling between them?

Comment: How about css-modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) ? Would it fit your requirement?

Comment: For scoped styles, consider using shadow DOM. For edge, use the polyfills

Comment: @MisterEpic Where'd the OP go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to DRY up the code, you could create one style-object and reuse it:

```
const Close = ({
                 fill, width, height, float,
               }) => {
  const style = { fill: 'none', stroke: `${fill}`, strokeMiterlimit: 10 }
  return (
    <svg width={ `${width}px` } height={ `${height}px` } viewBox="0 0 14.48 14.48" style={ { float: `${float}`, cursor: 'pointer' } }>
      <title>x</title>
      <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="Background">
          <line style={ style } x1="14.13" y1="0.35" x2="0.35" y2="14.13" />
          <line style={ style } x1="14.13" y1="14.13" x2="0.35" y2="0.35" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

This would also result in a small performance improvement since fewer objects would be created in each render cycle.

Comment: Yes, this is better, but this is a small example. My real world SVGs have many variations of inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

To combine the best of both worlds, you could create an external styles file, as you would for CSS, but with exported style objects. You could then import it into any file that needs it.

As example, main file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import * as Styles from './svgstyles';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg width="100" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 200">  
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style1} />
          <rect x="15" y="0" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style2} />
          <rect x="30" y="0" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style3} />
          <rect x="45" y="0" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style4} />
          <rect x="0" y="15" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style4} />
          <rect x="15" y="15" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style3} />
          <rect x="30" y="15" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style2} />
          <rect x="45" y="15" width="10" height="10" style={Styles.style1} />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And an external styles file:

```
export const style1 = {
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: "1",
  fill: "blue",
}

export const style2 = {
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: "1",
  fill: "green",
}

export const style3 = {
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: "1",
  fill: "yellow",
}

export const style4 = {
  ...style3,
  fill: "pink",
}
```

**[Live example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w49gpg)**

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I was in your place, Surely I use fonts instead of SVGs, but for your exact question, I prefer to use constant variables inside of my arrow function, just like below:

```
import React from 'react';

const Close = ({ fill, width, height, float }) => {
  const constStyle = { fill: 'none', stroke: `${fill}`, strokeMiterlimit: 10 };

  return (
    <svg
      width={`${width}px`}
      height={`${height}px`}
      viewBox="0 0 14.48 14.48"
      style={{ float: `${float}`, cursor: 'pointer' }}
    >
      <title>x</title>
      <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="Background">
          <line style={constStyle} x1="14.13" y1="0.35" x2="0.35" y2="14.13" />
          <line style={constStyle} x1="14.13" y1="14.13" x2="0.35" y2="0.35" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default Close;
```

Even, I make the line dimension variables as `props`, but I don't know what is your case exactly.

Hope this answer helps you.